# why does jquery ajax send multiple times?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

i have a message board. and you can comment on each message (bit like faceboook).
if you click the "comment" link a `textarea` slides down and you can write your comment.
but if you click "comment" then click cancel so that the `textarea` slides back up and them click comment again so that it slides back down again and leave a comment it will post the commment twice. so for every time the comment textarea slides into view and back it duplicates the comment.

```
    $("body").on("click",".new_comment", function(e){ // new comment link
e.preventDefault();
var post = $(this).parents('.message_container').siblings('#post_comment');
clearInterval(refreshBoard); //stop autorefresh
$(post).slideDown(400, function() { //slide textarea down

    $(".cancel_comment").on("click", function(e) { //cancel comment
        e.preventDefault();
        $(post).slideUp(400, function() { //slide textarea back up
        $('#comments').load('messages.php'); //reload div
        msgRefresh(); //starts autorefresh

        });         

        });
});
//the following posts the comment along with info//
    $("body").one("click", '.post_comment_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var anchor = $(this).parents('.update_comment')
.parents('#post_comment').siblings('.comment_list').find('ul:first');
            var comment = $(this).parents('.update_comment').children('textarea.post_comment').val();
            var user = $(this).parents('.update_comment').children('input.user').val();
            var msg_id = $(this).parents('.update_comment').children('input.message_id').val();
            if (comment == '')  $('#comments').load('messages.php');        
            else {
                $.post('messages.php', { 
                comment: comment, 
                message_id: msg_id, 
                post_comment: 'true' }, function(data) {
        //creatse new comment// 
                    $('body').append(data);
                    var newcomment = "<li><div class='comment_container'>
    <div class='date'>less than 1 minute ago</div>
    <div class='name'>" + user + " </div>
    <div class='info_bar'><div class='edit_comment'>
    <a href='#' class='comment_edit'>Edit</a>   </div>
    <span>|</span><a href='#' class='delete_comment'>Delete</a></div>
    <div class='fadeOut_comment'><div class='posted_comment'> " + 
    nl2br(htmlEntities(comment.trim())) + " </div></div></li>";
                            $(post).slideUp(400);
                            $(newcomment).fadeIn(500, function() {
                                $('#comments').load('messages.php');
                            }).appendTo(anchor);
                        });
                    }
                });

        });
```

so my question is why is this happening? and how do i stop it? if you need more info please ask. thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're biding the `.cancel_comment` click handler every time someone clicks the `.new_comment` link.

On the first comment it fires one time and binds again, second comment fires two times and binds again, etc. By the 10th comment it will fire 10 times because you attached 10 event handlers.

Then, because you call `msgRefresh();` inside this callback, it will append the same messages several times to the DOM.

To only bind it once take the following **outside** the `.new_comment` click callback.

```
$(".cancel_comment").on("click", function(e) { //cancel comment
    e.preventDefault();
    $(post).slideUp(400, function()
    { //slide textarea back up
        $('#comments').load('messages.php'); //reload div
        msgRefresh(); //starts autorefresh
    });         
});
```

And then bind it like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".cancel_comment", function(e)
{
    //cancel comment
});
```

I can see you're also biding at least one more event inside the `.new_comment` click callback. You should avoid doing this, do not bind anything inside a callback unless you really need to and you're 100% sure it won't be attached more than one time.

**EDIT**: The complete code might look something like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".cancel_comment", function(e) { //cancel comment
    e.preventDefault();
    $(post).slideUp(400, function() { //slide textarea back up
    $('#comments').load('messages.php'); //reload div
        msgRefresh(); //starts autorefresh

    });         

});

    $("body").on("click",".new_comment", function(e){ // new comment link
e.preventDefault();
var post = $(this).parents('.message_container').siblings('#post_comment');
clearInterval(refreshBoard); //stop autorefresh
$(post).slideDown(400, function() { //slide textarea down

});
//the following posts the comment along with info//
    $("body").one("click", '.post_comment_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var anchor = $(this).parents('.update_comment')
.parents('#post_comment').siblings('.comment_list').find('ul:first');
            var comment = $(this).parents('.update_comment').children('textarea.post_comment').val();
            var user = $(this).parents('.update_comment').children('input.user').val();
            var msg_id = $(this).parents('.update_comment').children('input.message_id').val();
            if (comment == '')  $('#comments').load('messages.php');        
            else {
                $.post('messages.php', { 
                comment: comment, 
                message_id: msg_id, 
                post_comment: 'true' }, function(data) {
        //creatse new comment// 
                    $('body').append(data);
                    var newcomment = "<li><div class='comment_container'>
    <div class='date'>less than 1 minute ago</div>
    <div class='name'>" + user + " </div>
    <div class='info_bar'><div class='edit_comment'>
    <a href='#' class='comment_edit'>Edit</a>   </div>
    <span>|</span><a href='#' class='delete_comment'>Delete</a></div>
    <div class='fadeOut_comment'><div class='posted_comment'> " + 
    nl2br(htmlEntities(comment.trim())) + " </div></div></li>";
                            $(post).slideUp(400);
                            $(newcomment).fadeIn(500, function() {
                                $('#comments').load('messages.php');
                            }).appendTo(anchor);
                        });
                    }
                });

        });
```

Comment: errr thanx for help. i'm not that experienced with jquery as you can see. i don't really understand the qwhole binding thing. i did what you said tho and it still does it ?????

Comment: ok actually you were right. i took the post comment button outside of .new_comment and ti tseems to work now. although it has broken sumin and caused another problem but ill try and get round it. thank you

Comment: @dragonvsphoenix the issue I was talking about isn't related with your HTML. I don't think you need to move your button, just move the portion of the code I quoted outside of this callback function: `$("body").on("click",".new_comment", function(e){//This is the callback I'm refering to }`

Comment: yeh sorry i did that, just explained it wrong. i didnt change the html. it works now anyway. thanx

Comment: @dragonvsphoenix if it's still of any help, please see my update to the answer.

Comment: yes that is what i already done...thanx....again....i just had to re-do some of the selectors cos moving the code changed them. just got issues with my `.one()` mouse event now. i posted a new question if you'd like to answer :)